Handling Infinite Values in Seaborn
I'm trying to plot a pairplot of my dataset using Seaborn, but I'm encountering an error related to infinite values. Here is the code I'm using:
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.pairplot(df_train[cols], height=2.5)
plt.show()

However, I get the following warning:
C:\Users\jpino\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\seaborn_oldcore.py:1119: FutureWarning: use_inf_as_na option is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Convert inf values to NaN before operating instead.
with pd.option_context('mode.use_inf_as_na', True):

How can I handle the infinite values in my dataset to avoid this warning and successfully plot the pairplot?

This warning means you should upgrade seaborn. See github issue 3462: this and related warnings are handled in seaborn 0.13. The warning is just a natural side effect of python packages evolving over time. (As it is just a warning, everything still works fine, until you'd further upgrade pandas without upgrading seaborn).
